# django.template.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError: Could not parse the remainder: '/bootstrap4/popper.js'' from 'styles/bootstrap4/popper.js''

Tags: django, bootstrap-4

I have created the static directory from which  I am loading the template.

```
{% load static %}
```

I am getting this error as

```
django.template.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError: Could not parse the remainder: '/bootstrap4/popper.js'' from 'styles/bootstrap4/popper.js''
```

Hare's how I am loading bootstarp.

```
<script src="{% static 'js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js' %}"></script>
<script src="{% static styles/bootstrap4/popper.js' %}"></script>
<script src="{% static styles/bootstrap4/bootstrap.min.js' %}"></script>
```

can someone help me with this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may be forgot to close your quotation `' '` in line 2 and 3 . check this please :

```
<script src="{% static 'js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js' %}"></script>
<script src="{% static 'styles/bootstrap4/popper.js' %}"></script>
<script src="{% static 'styles/bootstrap4/bootstrap.min.js' %}"></script>
```

Comment: did u closed like it `'styles/bootstrap4/popper.js'` ??